# How to add a custom CalloutView loaded from nib file

Tags: iphone, ios, mkannotation, callouts

I'm trying to make a custom Callout view for AnnotationView. I had seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6955392/810661), and seems a good solution (it works). I'm trying to load a UIView from a nib file, and the UIView appears, but his buttons don't work, don't get pushed.

Is there a way of doing this?? How can I load the UIView from a nib file and get the buttons working??
Or maybe anyone help me finding a good solution.

Thanks

Here's the code I'm using:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    if(selected)
    {
        //Add custom view to self...
        calloutView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        [self addSubview:calloutView];
    }
    else
    {
        //Remove custom view...
        if (calloutView) {
            [calloutView removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Throw an `NSLog(@"My callout view is: %@",calloutView)` just after the line where you load the view from the nib, to make sure it's getting the right object.

Comment: yes, its the same object, is an instance var..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem: [gik-animated-callout](https://github.com/GiK/gik-animated-callout)

Answer (score 0):

The nib for your custom UIView should have a backing UIView class (MyCustomView.h/.m).  In Interface Builder you will want to set the custom class value under the identity inspector to your custom class.  Once this is done you would hook up the UIButton in the nib to your desired IBAction by dragging the connection (touch up inside likely) from the bottom to the main view under the objects section (NOT the file's owner as you may be used to).

Hopefully that helps

~Good Luck

Comment: Maybe I didn't make myself clear. The problem is not calling an IBAction. The problem is that the buttons are not touchables. If I `presentModalViewController` a `UIViewController` with his view set to the same calloutView, they buttons are touchables.