# How to avoid the default CallOutView to appear?

Tags: iphone, ios, mkannotation, callouts

I'm trying to make a custom Callout view for AnnotationView. I had seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8945376/810661).
And please see the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8945376/810661)

I'm able to load the custom view. 
But How to avoid the default CallOutView to appear??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your MKAnnotationView set the canShowCallout to NO

Comment: thanks, it works!! Can you help me with this [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8945376/810661)